# Multiple Columns in One Step in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m, customcolumn

I want to add multiple columns in one step only.

I was able to find a custom function below.

```
 Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1") & {{null},{null}},
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns1") & {"NewCust1","NewCust2"}
        )
```

It will add 2 columns with null on each cells however what I want to do is that all new columns is equal to an existing Column called Source.Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easier way.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUUoC4mSl2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Source.Name = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn( Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each  [NewCust1=[Source.Name], NewCust2=[Source.Name]]), "Custom", {"NewCust1", "NewCust2"})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Hello Davide, Thank you so much, it works. I'm just curious though, regarding the ExpandRecordColumn. Can it be done by simply using the Ribbon or it can only be done by manually coding it?

Comment: You're welcome. You have to write it using code if you want to do it in 1 step.